# wrap_text with openpyxl. How to use documentation to resolve deprecation warning?

Tags: python, openpyxl, python-3.7

I run the following openpyxl command to wrap text in all rows after row 9. It works fine but throws a deprecation warning. I'd love to figure out how to use documentation such as https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ to determine the current, non-deprecated, way to wrap_text. But I always find the documentation confusing and unhelpful to me. For example, if I search for wrap_text I get this: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.styles.alignment.html#openpyxl.styles.alignment.Alignment.wrapText

But that tells me nothing about how to wrap text. Do I simply not know know how to use the documentation? Is there some great mystery I am to unravel so I don't have to endlessly google how to use openpyxl? How does one look at such documentation and figure out out how to wrap_text in a cell?

Here is the code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

file1 = "C:\\folder\\inputFile1.xlsx"
wb=load_workbook(file1)
ws = wb.active
for rows in ws.iter_rows(min_row=10, max_row=None, min_col=None, max_col=None):
    for cell in rows:
       cell.alignment =  cell.alignment.copy(wrapText=True)
    wb.save('C:\\folder\file1_wrap.xlsx')
```

here is the deprecation warning:

C:\Users\Jcurran\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:10: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function copy (Use copy(obj) or cell.obj = cell.obj + other).
Remove the CWD from sys.path while we load stuff.

How might I figure out the way to find the information required to use the current (non-deprecated) approach to wrapping text in cells via the documentation at https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/?

I am using Jupyter for my environment. Shift tab or tab doesn't give me anything useful.

Any suggestions? I crave self sufficiency but can't grasp how to navigate the documentation for answer. There must be some clue somewhere? Some source code perhaps that I do not know how to locate?

Comment: Using version `3.0.0`, didn't get a `DeprecationWarning`. [Edit] your question and add the `print(openpyxl.__version__)`

Comment: wow. I could have sworn I downloaded the latest openpyxl. I guess I did not.  >>> import openpyxl
>>> openpyxl.__version__
'2.5.14'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I learned that I did not have the latest openpyxl version. pip install openpyxl installed 2.5. I upgraded it to 3.0.
Now when I look at https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html it makes more sense :-)

I now know that the "Working with Styles" section of the openpyxl 3.0 documentation is the place to go for formatting data.

So I click that, and go to https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html

That page shows me this:

```
>>> alignment=Alignment(horizontal='general',
...                     vertical='bottom',
...                     text_rotation=0,
...                     wrap_text=False,
...                     shrink_to_fit=False,
...                     indent=0)
```

and I could use that info to wrap text with this line:

```
cell.alignment = Alignment(wrapText=True)
```

Now things are starting to make sense for me.  :-) Thanks!